# Creating a python class which can return both a representation of itself and be callable with a calculated result

Tags: python, class

I want to have a class that represents a polynomial function. When calling an instance of the class, I want to see a string representation of that function

e.g.

```
f = Polynomial([0,1,2])
f
> +2²
```

This is fine, I just write a suitable `__repr__` function - it would also be nice to be able to evaluate this function at a given value of  - and so what I'd like to do is something like:

```
f(3)
> 21
```

So how do I do this? Do I write a second overloaded `__repr__` function with the additional parameter, or do I alter the existing `__repr__` so it has an optional argument?

Sadly, I can't seem to get the first working, and using the second of these options, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Polynomial' object is not callable
```

Any ideas on having this dual behaviour so:

```
f
> +2²
```

and

```
f(3)
> 21
```

The first is just the representation of f, and the second, it's evaluation at =3.

Comment: I can't understand why you think this has anything to do with `__repr__`. If you want a class instance to do something when called, you should define `__call__`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I’ve not come across `__call__` before and `__repr__` felt related because it’s what you get when you reference an instance of a class directly with no additional dot-method call. Using the principle of the least amount of surprise I thought there might be a way of overloading `__repr__` to behave differently when passed a parameter. But that’s probably more due to my previous life/bias as a java dabbler (and javas fondness for overloading) than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to support *calling* your object, then just implement the [`__call__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__), and return a result that gives the desired representation.

If, for a given value of `x`, the result is always an integer, just returning that integer suffices:

```
class Polynomial:
    X = "\U0001d465"
    X_squared = X + "\u00b2"

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __repr__(self):
        parts = []
        if self.a:
            a = self.X_squared
            if self.a > 1:
                a = f"{self.a}{a}"
            parts.append(a)
        if self.b:
            b = self.X
            if self.b > 1:
                b = f"{self.b}{b}"
            parts.append(b)
        if self.c:
            parts.append(str(self.c))
        if not parts:
            parts = ['0']
        return ' + '.join(parts)

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.a * (x ** 2) + self.b * x + self.c
```

which achieves the output you are looking for:

```
>>> p = Polynomial(2, 1, 0)
>>> p
2² + 
>>> p(3)
21
```

Note that `__repr__` is usually intended to produce *debugging output*. There is no configuration possible, an object has a specific state, and `__repr__` should show that state, more or less.

If you want to make string formatting configurable, then look at the [`__format__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__), used by [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format). That's probably not that suitable for your uses if you want to enable your objects to be used in an interactive Python setting.

You may also want to study how the [SymPy project handles output formatting](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html); that project [explicitly avoids using `__repr__`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html#srepr-fn). Instead, outside of IPython they set a custom [`sys.displayhook()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) to use their own pretty-printing functions instead of `repr()` when a sympy-project object is being displayed. For details, see the [`sympy.interactive.printing` module source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/4ab4f8b69462daf1cbdd2550221a6c1e654db3d5/sympy/interactive/printing.py).